# How to update and view own entities in yii2

Tags: yii2

I need to restrict only own user can update and view his records in yii2. Also other user cannot update and view another user entities via changing record id in URL.

Comment: You should read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html ...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is via RBAC You check the tutorials here:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFOIUeU-Y74
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9-tBshv3Uo

Else you can do it via placing if conditions in your model and views

i.e

your table must have `owner_id` field that will contain owner id of the entity.

You can then override the `find()` method in your model i.e

```
public static function find()
    {
        $find = parent::find();
        // filter all records by loggedin id with owner_id match
        $find->andWhere(['owner_id' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->id]);

        return $find;
    }
```

and in your controller you can place if condition like:

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        
        if($model->owner_id != \Yii::$app->user->identity->id) {
            throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;
        }

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: i tried this one. i got error in something like below;SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `postjob` LEFT JOIN `companyprofile` ON `postjob`.`company_id` = `companyprofile`.`id` WHERE ((((`user_id`=156) OR (`feature`='1')) OR (`feature`='0')) AND (`block`='Unblock')) AND (`job_status`='1') so, i need to restrict other user cannot view and update records details via record id changes in url.

Comment: It means, that two or more tables contain column with name `user_id`, it might be possible that your `companyprofile` and `postjob` table both have `user_id` column, in this case you need to be specific with your column name.  i.e something like `postjob`.`user_id`

Comment: thank u for information i need before and after action for update Action in controller.

Comment: Better if you can post the Sample code so that we can see what exactly is needed

Comment: i used above code. it's working fine in recruiter side, but i also need jobseeker also view job details and not able to update job.

Comment: now  i am logged in jobseeker account, i can view jobs, but i am not able to update jobs,  here is my url:http://192.168.1.51/basic/web/index.php?r=postjob%2Fview&id=241. suppose i change view into update in url  means update form will show. i need to restrict these thingd from jobseeker. and also recruiter can update his own jobs only not for othres.

Comment: Do you mean you want only the authorized person to be able to update the record ? if so you can use same code as in actionView for restriction.

Comment: i used it. but recruiter can view and update job details but jobseeker not able to view jobs. i need jobseeker want to view jobs but not able to update jobs, and also recruiter can view and update his jobs only. not for other recruiter jobs.

Comment: As per your original question, "I need to restrict only own user can update and view his records in yii2", this answer is basic implementation, if you want to go with the advanced solution you need to follow this guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: can i hide id value in url. if i can means it's solved.

Comment: i already read above link. but it's not working i need only owner of the record user can update and view  his record.

Comment: Your this statement is conflicting with your previous statement: "i used it. but recruiter can view and update job details but jobseeker not able to view jobs. i need jobseeker want to view jobs but not able to update jobs, and also recruiter can view and update his jobs only. not for other recruiter jobs." OR there is some confusion here.. So best solution is to update your question with your real code sample.

Comment: i have three  users like jobseeker,recruiter and subemployee.here jobseeker can view jobs but not able to update jobs by changing url record id.At the same time Recruiter can view and update his jobs.and also subemployee can view and update his jobs. NOTE:SUBEMPLOYEE'S ARE CREATED BY RECRUITER.Here recruiter can view jobs which hasbeen created by his subemployee.......